# Subscribe and Publish a arbitrary topic!

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I would like to subscribe to the Laserscan data and process it and publish something.
Unfortunately, I keep getting error.
I appreciate if you help.
here is my code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float32.h>

std_msgs::Float32 minval;

void Callback_laser(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan)
{

minval = scan->ranges[0];
    for(int i=0;i<scan->ranges.size();i++)
    {
        if(scan->ranges[i]<minval or minval!=minval)
           minval=scan->ranges[i];
    }

}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "subscribing"); 
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    ros::Subscriber laser_subscriber = n.subscribe<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("scan", 1000, Callback_laser);

    ros::Publisher pub=n.advertise<std_msgs::Float32>("minval", 1000);

    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

      while (ros::ok())
      {
         pub.publish(minval);
         ros::spinOnce();
         loop_rate.sleep();
      }


     return 0; 
}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228957/subscribe-and-publish-a-arbitrary-topic!/) by [Reza1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/8496/reza1984/) on ROS Answers with karma: 70 on 2016-03-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Peris](https://answers.ros.org/users/1108/martin-peris/) on 2016-03-13**:
Hi, it would be useful if you could attach any error logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks I solved my problem. Here is the code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sensor_msgs/LaserScan.h>
#include <std_msgs/Float32.h>

std_msgs::Float32 mindist;

void Callback_laser(const sensor_msgs::LaserScan::ConstPtr& scan)
{

float minval = scan->ranges[0];
    for(int i=0;i<scan->ranges.size();i++)
    {
        if(scan->ranges[i]<minval or minval!=minval)
           minval=scan->ranges[i];
    }

       ROS_INFO("min_range[%f] \n",minval);

       mindist.data=minval;

}



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "subscribing"); 

    ros::NodeHandle n;

    ros::Subscriber laser_subscriber = n.subscribe<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("scan", 1000, Callback_laser);

    ros::Publisher pub=n.advertise<std_msgs::Float32>("mindist", 1000);
     
    ros::Rate loop_rate(10);

      while (ros::ok())
      {

         pub.publish(mindist);
         ros::spinOnce();
         loop_rate.sleep();
      }

     return 0; 

}
```

---

Originally posted by [Reza1984](https://answers.ros.org/users/8496/reza1984/) with karma: 70 on 2016-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0